# How do you have two random word generators on one screen

Tags: ios, swift, random, words

I am currently working on an app where you can swipe two halves of the phone screen separately with each half generating a random word when you swipe left.

I have created a list of words for the top half of the screen that randomly generate words. How would I apply this same method for the bottom half of the screen? I have got 2 images of the code that I currently have in view controller

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // put the labels and the buttons
    @IBOutlet var InspirationalThought: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var Click: UIButton!

    //what the label is going to show

    var quotes = ["Geometrics", "Vectors", "Celebration", "Triangle",      "Landscapes", "Seasons", "Snow", "Rain", "Sunrays", "Stencils", "Paint", "Graphics", "Graffiti", "Sports","Fashion","Ancient Greek", "Philosophers", "Fairy tales", "Fantasy", "Clouds", "Mystery", "Time Clocks", "Canvas", "Tie-dye", "Glitter", "Dessert", "Desert", "Energy", "Astrology", "Solar Systems", "Sea", "Beach", "Sphere", "Roots", "Lights", "Darks", "Fire", "Air", "Aperture", "Long exposure", "Portraits", "World", "Travel", "Architecture", "Freedom", "Old", "New", "Urban", "Lenses", "Fisheye", "Chords", "Music notes", "Spices", "Herbs", "Natural", "Marbles", "Wood", "Trees", "Forests", "Interior","Mammals", "Reptiles", "Ocean", "Birds", "Photography", "Exposure", "Opaque", "Translucent", "Freestyle", "Spots", "Stripes", "Zig Zag", "Spiral", "Glass", "Feathers", "Calm", "Bulb", "Heat", "Cold", "Stitches", "Views", "Birds", "Sunset", "Earth"]

    var whichQuotestoChoose = 0

    // what the button is going to show
    var ButtonText = ["Inspiration", "Tell me more", "more inspirational"]
    var whichButtonTexttoChoose = 0

    @IBAction func ClickButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
        chooseAQuote()
        chooseTextonButton()
    }

    func chooseAQuote(){
        showTheQuote()
        whichQuotestoChoose = Int(arc4random_uniform (84))
    }

    func showTheQuote(){
        InspirationalThought.text = "\(quotes[whichQuotestoChoose])"
    }

    func chooseTextonButton(){
        Click.setTitle("\(ButtonText[whichButtonTexttoChoose])", forState:UIControlState.Normal)
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: So which screen you are looking for the answer too andhas code been added for that? Is it only once VC

Comment: The first screen is what i currently have and that is where the code is from . yes its only one VC.The second screen is what i want it too look like its a screenshot of a storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do it. 
If your background remains the same, with top and bottom color always same with star then get it as a image.

Add a imageView and set the image as background image

Add 2 UIView's view1 and view2 as top and bottom view. Set there background color as clearColor and tag as 1 and 2 respectively

Add swipe gesture 2 both of them with same selector.

Add UILabel to each namely view label1 and label2.

Create a string to hold the text from quotes when swipped. Based on the tag of the view, set the label text accordingly.

Below is the sample implementation:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var view1: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var view2: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!

var displayString: String?
var quotes = ["Geometrics", "Vectors", "Celebration", "Triangle",      "Landscapes", "Seasons", "Snow", "Rain", "Sunrays", "Stencils", "Paint", "Graphics", "Graffiti", "Sports","Fashion","Ancient Greek", "Philosophers", "Fairy tales", "Fantasy", "Clouds", "Mystery", "Time Clocks", "Canvas", "Tie-dye", "Glitter", "Dessert", "Desert", "Energy", "Astrology", "Solar Systems", "Sea", "Beach", "Sphere", "Roots", "Lights", "Darks", "Fire", "Air", "Aperture", "Long exposure", "Portraits", "World", "Travel", "Architecture", "Freedom", "Old", "New", "Urban", "Lenses", "Fisheye", "Chords", "Music notes", "Spices", "Herbs", "Natural", "Marbles", "Wood", "Trees", "Forests", "Interior","Mammals", "Reptiles", "Ocean", "Birds", "Photography", "Exposure", "Opaque", "Translucent", "Freestyle", "Spots", "Stripes", "Zig Zag", "Spiral", "Glass", "Feathers", "Calm", "Bulb", "Heat", "Cold", "Stitches", "Views", "Birds", "Sunset", "Earth"]

var whichQuotestoChoose = 0

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.viewSwipped(_:)))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    view1.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

    let swipeLeft1 = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.viewSwipped(_:)))
    swipeLeft1.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirection.Left
    view2.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft1)
}

func viewSwipped(gesture: UIGestureRecognizer) {
    self.chooseAQuote()
    if let swippedView = gesture.view {
        if swippedView.tag == 1 {
            label1.leftToRightAnimation()
            label1.text = displayString
        } else {
            label2.leftToRightAnimation()
            label2.text = displayString
        }
    }
}

func chooseAQuote() {
    displayString = quotes[whichQuotestoChoose]
    whichQuotestoChoose = Int(arc4random_uniform (84)) 
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}

extension UIView {
    func leftToRightAnimation(duration: NSTimeInterval = 0.5, completionDelegate: AnyObject? = nil) {
    // Create a CATransition object
    let leftToRightTransition = CATransition()

    // Set its callback delegate to the completionDelegate that was provided
    if let delegate: AnyObject = completionDelegate {
        leftToRightTransition.delegate = delegate
    }

    leftToRightTransition.type = kCATransitionPush
    leftToRightTransition.subtype = kCATransitionFromRight
    leftToRightTransition.duration = duration
    leftToRightTransition.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut)
    leftToRightTransition.fillMode = kCAFillModeRemoved

    // Add the animation to the View's layer
    self.layer.addAnimation(leftToRightTransition, forKey: "leftToRightTransition")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. The instructions above will result in the word being able to swipe left and then be replaced with another random word from the generator? Do i implement the code underneath my original code in the view controller ? How do i place in the code for the second list of words for the bottom half of the screen?

Comment: No. It will just change the label text. Swipe is set on the vie so anywhere you swipe word will be changed. You can add some animation to add that feature.

Comment: Where abouts do i place the code example into my code? and how would i code the bottom list of words ?

Comment: In your ViewController itself, remove the ClickButtonClicked method and add whatever i have given. Based on the view swiped the gesturerecognizer will updated the label of that view.

Comment: There are several errors and it doesn't seem to be working

Comment: That was a huge help!! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad it helped. Also will update the post with label slide animation.