# How do i implement a random generator on 2 different views on the same view controller?

Tags: xcode, swift

Im very new to Xcode and swipe , any help is much appreciated. I have created a random generator for a words list on the top half of the screen(the top label, this is included in the code). How do i adapt this code so that i can use a different list of words on the bottom half of the screen ( the bottom label is not attatched to any code)? but for the same click button to randomise both list of words ? 
[The layout of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNah0.png)

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    // put the labels and the buttons

```
@IBOutlet var InspirationalThought: UILabel!

@IBOutlet var Click: UIButton!

//what the label is going to show
var quotes = ["Geometrics", "Vectors", "Celebration", "Triangle", "Landscapes", "Seasons", "Snow", "Rain", "Sunrays", "Stencils", "Paint", "Graphics", "Graffiti", "Sports","Fashion",
    "Ancient Greek", "Philosophers", "Fairy Tales", "Fantasy", "Clouds", "Mystery", "Time Clocks", "Canvas", "Tie-dye", "Glitter", "Dessert", "Desert", "Energy", "Astrology", "Solar Systems", "Sea", "Beach", "Sphere", "Roots", "Lights", "Darks", "Fire", "Air",
          "Aperture", "Long exposure", "Portraits", "World", "Travel", "Architecture", "Freedom", "Old", "New", "Urban", "Lenses", "Fisheye", "Chords", "Music Notes", "Spices", "Herbs", "Natural", "Marbles", "Wood", "Trees", "Forests", "Interior",
          "Mammals", "Reptiles", "Ocean", "Birds", "Photography", "Exposure", "Opaque", "Translucent", "Freestyle", "Spots", "Stripes", "Zig Zag", "Spiral", "Glass", "Feathers", "Calm", "Bulb", "Heat", "Cold", "Stitches", "Views", "Birds", "Sunset", "Earth"]

var whichQuotestoChoose = 0

// what the button is going to show

var ButtonText = ["Inspiration", "Tell me more", "more inspirational"]
var whichButtonTexttoChoose = 0





override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()


}



@IBAction func ClickButtonClicked(sender: UIButton) {
    chooseAQuote()
    chooseTextonButton()

}

func chooseAQuote(){
    showTheQuote()
    whichQuotestoChoose = Int(arc4random_uniform (84))

}
func showTheQuote(){
    InspirationalThought.text = "\(quotes[whichQuotestoChoose])"

}
func chooseTextonButton(){
    Click.setTitle("\(ButtonText[whichButtonTexttoChoose])", forState: UIControlState.Normal)


}
```

}

Comment: I'm a bit confused as there is only one label in the code, yet you have two in the layout.

Comment: yeah sorry, the bottom label isn't connected to the code as of yet.

Comment: Could you [edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/37100997/edit) once you do so?

Comment: How is this question different from [your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37094855/how-do-you-have-two-random-word-generators-on-one-screen)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Use extension it is global. you can use shuffle the array and print the quote. you can declare quotes array global so you can access it in any view controller.**

```
   var quotes = ["Geometrics", "Vectors", "Celebration", "Triangle", "Landscapes", "Seasons", "Snow", "Rain", "Sunrays", "Stencils", "Paint", "Graphics", "Graffiti", "Sports","Fashion",
              "Ancient Greek", "Philosophers", "Fairy Tales", "Fantasy", "Clouds", "Mystery", "Time Clocks", "Canvas", "Tie-dye", "Glitter", "Dessert", "Desert", "Energy", "Astrology", "Solar Systems", "Sea", "Beach", "Sphere", "Roots", "Lights", "Darks", "Fire", "Air",
              "Aperture", "Long exposure", "Portraits", "World", "Travel", "Architecture", "Freedom", "Old", "New", "Urban", "Lenses", "Fisheye", "Chords", "Music Notes", "Spices", "Herbs", "Natural", "Marbles", "Wood", "Trees", "Forests", "Interior",
              "Mammals", "Reptiles", "Ocean", "Birds", "Photography", "Exposure", "Opaque", "Translucent", "Freestyle", "Spots", "Stripes", "Zig Zag", "Spiral", "Glass", "Feathers", "Calm", "Bulb", "Heat", "Cold", "Stitches", "Views", "Birds", "Sunset", "Earth"]

extension CollectionType {
    /// Return a copy of `self` with its elements shuffled
    func shuffle() -> [Generator.Element] {
        var list = Array(self)
        list.shuffleInPlace()
        return list
    }
}

extension MutableCollectionType where Index == Int {
    /// Shuffle the elements of `self` in-place.
    mutating func shuffleInPlace() {
        // empty and single-element collections don't shuffle
        if count < 2 { return }

        for i in 0..<count - 1 {
            let j = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(count - i))) + i
            guard i != j else { continue }
            swap(&self[i], &self[j])
        }
    }
}

quotes = quotes.shuffle()

print(quotes[0])  // Print random quote
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Shuffle extension are not written by me. 
Credits **Nate Cook** : 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24029847/2803960